# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord.py

I was creating a discord bot, and when I used a command(!buy @Role), it crashed with:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - {} WHERE id = {}".format(("SELECT cost FROM shop WHERE role_id = {}".format(role.id)).fetchone()[0], ctx.author.id))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

I don't understand what's up, because role id is integer! Here code is:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
        role_id INT,
        id INT,
        cost BIGINT
    )""")

@client.command(aliases = ['buy', 'buy-role'])
async def __buy(ctx, role: discord.Role = None):
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, choose a role, which you want to buy!")
    else:
        if role in ctx.author.roles:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, you already have this role!")
        elif cursor.execute("SELECT cost FROM shop WHERE role_id = {}".format(role.id)).fetchone()[0] > cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]:
            await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.author}**, not enough money!')
        else:
            await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - {} WHERE id = {}".format(("SELECT cost FROM shop WHERE role_id = {}".format(role.id)).fetchone()[0], ctx.author.id))
            connection.commit()

            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')

client.run('MY TOKEN')
```

**PLEASE HELP!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = %s WHERE id = %s", [value1, value2])
```

and you can create a variable for the coins in the database and then subtract the price.